# How to move to the delete button and click on that in Selenium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, salesforce

[image]

[image]

This is a Salesforce lightening page and while deleting the object I am getting a modal dialog box where I am unable to move to click on that. Alert class is not working to move onto the page.

Please find the code below:

```
 public static void Delete_Object(WebDriver driver) throws InterruptedException

 {
      // (new WebDriverWait(driver, 30)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(("//label[contains(@for,'globalQuickfind')]/preceding::div/input[contains(@id,'globalQuickfind')]")))).sendKeys("java dev");

     try
     {

       (new WebDriverWait(driver, 30)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(("//span[.='Java_dev__c']//following::td[5]//a")))).click();


       (new WebDriverWait(driver, 30)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(("//span[.='Delete']//span")))).click();

       Thread.sleep(5000);

      (new WebDriverWait(driver, 30)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(("//button[@title=\"Close this window\"]")))).click();

     }

   catch(Exception e)
     {
       System.out.println(e.getMessage());
     }


 }
```

Here is the html code:

```html
<div class="panel slds-modal slds-fade-in-open" aria-labelledby="title_4828:0" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-modal="true" data-aura-rendered-by="4842:0">
  <div class="modal-container slds-modal__container" data-aura-rendered-by="4843:0">
<div class="modal-header slds-modal__header empty slds-modal__header--empty" data-aura-rendered-by="4844:0">
  <!--render facet: 4845:0--><!--render facet: 4846:0--><!--render facet: 4847:0-->
  <button class="slds-button slds-modal__close closeIcon slds-button_icon-bare slds-button_icon-inverse" type="button" title="Close this window" data-aura-rendered-by="4832:0">
    <lightning-primitive-icon data-aura-rendered-by="4833:0" lightning-primitive-icon_primitive-icon="">
      <svg focusable="false" data-key="close" aria-hidden="true" class="slds-button__icon slds-button__icon_large slds-button_icon-inverse" lightning-primitive-icon_primitive-icon="">
        <use xlink:href="/_slds/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg?cache=9.8.0#close" lightning-primitive-icon_primitive-icon=""></use>
      </svg>
    </lightning-primitive-icon>
    <span class="slds-assistive-text" data-aura-rendered-by="4835:0">Close this window</span>
  </button>
</div>
<div class="modal-body scrollable slds-modal__content slds-p-around--medium" data-aura-rendered-by="4850:0" data-scoped-scroll="true">
  <!--render facet: 4837:0-->
  <div data-aura-rendered-by="4798:0" class="objectManagerCustomObjectDeleteWarning" data-aura-class="objectManagerCustomObjectDeleteWarning">
    <p data-aura-rendered-by="4799:0">Deleting a custom object does the following:</p>
    <ul data-aura-rendered-by="4801:0">
      <li data-aura-rendered-by="4802:0">Deletes all the data that currently exists in all records of that custom object</li>
      <li data-aura-rendered-by="4804:0">Deletes all tracked history data associated with the custom object</li>
      <li data-aura-rendered-by="4806:0">Deletes the custom tab and list views for the object</li>
      <li data-aura-rendered-by="4808:0">Deletes workflow rules and actions that use the object</li>
      <li data-aura-rendered-by="4810:0">Hides the custom object definition and all related definitions</li>
      <li data-aura-rendered-by="4812:0">Hides the object's data records and all related data records</li>
      <li data-aura-rendered-by="4814:0">Disables report types for which this is the main object</li>
      <li data-aura-rendered-by="4816:0">Disables custom reports for which this is the main object</li>
      <li data-aura-rendered-by="4818:0">Deactivates custom formula fields on the object</li>
      <li data-aura-rendered-by="4820:0">Deactivates custom validation rules and approval processes on the object</li>
      <li data-aura-rendered-by="4822:0">Deactivates and deletes the Lightning Pages associated with the custom object.</li>
    </ul>
    <p data-aura-rendered-by="4824:0">In order to preserve a record of data for future reference, run a data export before deleting custom objects by clicking Data | Data Export.</p>
    <p data-aura-rendered-by="4826:0">After you've deleted this custom object, it appears in the deleted objects list for 15 days. During that time, you can either undelete it to restore it and all the data stored in it, or delete it permanently. When you undelete a custom object, some of its properties might be lost or changed.  After 15 days, the object and its data are permanently deleted.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer slds-modal__footer" data-aura-rendered-by="4871:0">
  <div data-aura-rendered-by="4855:0" class="forceModalActionContainer--footerAction forceModalActionContainer" data-aura-class="forceModalActionContainer--footerAction forceModalActionContainer">
    <button class="slds-button slds-button--neutral uiButton--default uiButton--brand uiButton forceActionButton" aria-live="off" type="button" title="delete" data-aura-rendered-by="4862:0" data-aura-class="uiButton--default uiButton--brand uiButton forceActionButton">
      <!--render facet: 4863:0--><span class=" label bBody" dir="ltr" data-aura-rendered-by="4865:0">Delete</span><!--render facet: 4860:0-->
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please find the attached screenshot:

[image]

Comment: paste the HTML in text format.

Comment: When you have text output, [don't take a picture but copy paste the output in your POST](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text) The html can be copied as well with right click -> copy as outerHTML.

Comment: you can see in the screenshot @cruisepandey

Comment: No, need the innerHTML of the div

Comment: @AnuragShrivastava : It's never a good thing to post picture unless it's necessary. Share the HTML code in text format. So that we can help you more effectively.

Comment: @AnuragShrivastava , share your current code and exception log

Comment: i have shared the html code.

Comment: looks like that element is contained in an iframe. Can you share complete html of the page?

Comment: @theGuy actually there is no iframe inside the page.

Comment: are you getting any exception when trying to locate that element? Also show us your code for click action

Comment: @theGuy please find the code i have attached

Comment: @Andersson  I am not receiving any exception and above i have attached the code

Comment: your locator doesn't seem right to me, there is an extra `//span` at the end of your delete button locator

Comment: @theGuy but with the same locator it's getting located on the page.

Comment: @theGuy the problem is not in the above code which you are talking about here is the problem in the next line: (new WebDriverWait(driver, 30)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(("//button[@title=\"Close this window\"]")))).click();

Comment: can you be more clear on your above comments? what do you mean by "but with the same locator it's getting located on the page" and what is the problem in the next line?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179387/discussion-between-anurag-shrivastava-and-theguy).

Comment: Why do you have 3 screenshots of the same dialog? It's not clear why three are needed. You should either remove the 2 redundant ones or explain what is different, etc.

Comment: @jeffc So after looking into the html code or screenshot , did you reach to the answer?

Comment: I posted an answer. I'm not sure what you are saying.

Answer (score 0):

The dialog pictured is not an alert, it's just an HTML dialog. An alert is a [Javascript alert](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert) and the like and does not contain HTML.

To click the Delete button in the dialog, you just need a CSS locator like

```
button[title='delete']
```

I've cleaned up your code. Since all your waits are the same, you can define a single wait and reuse it.

```
public static void Delete_Object(WebDriver driver) throws InterruptedException
{
    try
    {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(("//span[.='Java_dev__c']//following::td[5]//a")))).click();
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("button[title='delete']"))).click();
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(("//button[@title=\"Close this window\"]")))).click();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: just out of curiosity, why it has to be a css selector? I do prefer css locators since its fast but will xpath won't work in this case?

Comment: @theGuy It doesn't have to be a CSS selector I just prefer them because they are faster, better supported, etc. I can't think of any locator that a CSS selector can find that can't be converted to XPath... but there are some XPaths that cannot be converted to CSS selectors. For example, anything that locates an element based on contained text or does DOM navigation cannot be done in CSS.

Comment: @theGuy but you could not provide me the answer of the question.

Comment: @theGuy it would be really great if you help me in this case

Comment: I guess you left the room while I was away, I have asked you to try javascript solution in my last comment in chat. Also, you can try the answer provided by JeffC,

Answer (score 0):

```
       WebElement delete = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 30)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[.='Delete']"))); 
       ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", delete);
```

Thanks a lot @theGuy  You guys are really awesome.
so this script has worked.
Thanks again